# Javascript analyse string and insert visualization into page

Tags: javascript, visualization, data-visualization, google-visualization

windowData[] is an array of strings to analyse, 
the function analyse it is analyse(windowData), it willloop through windowData, and for each string, it adds a block, which will be containing google chart visualization of the string, into index.html, and then analyse the string and show the results.

so it is like:

```
windowData=[json1,json2,json3,json4]//contains large JSON objects

function analyse(windowData){
 for(var i=0;i<windowData.length;i++){
   var f = windowData[i];
   var html = '<div id="1googoleChart'+i+'></div>' +
               '<div id="2googoleChart'+i+'></div>' +
               '<div id="3googoleChart'+i+'></div>' +
               '<div id="4googoleChart'+i+'></div>' 

      analyseString();
      loadGoogleCharts();
   }
}
```

if there are less than 4 string(large JSON files) in windowData, the results are well displayed after the analyse function, BUT if there are more than 4 strings(takes a while to analyse), the analyse function did perform and get results but did NOT display in the google charts! anyone knows why is that? I am so puzzled now...

Comment: I believe the Google charts load before the calculation/analyse function completes, which results in no data on chart.

Comment: mhhh, I tried with callback function..did not work...

Comment: Oh my...I changed to a better computer , the Problem solved! Dont know why but my notebook is quite old model.